remove file from GCS with DVC
Is there any way to remove a credential file that I've 'dvc pushed' to GCS?
I can't access the GCS interface via the browser either
I tried to do dvc rm data/jsons/creds.json but it says that 'dvc.yaml' doesn't exist. I looked for some things in the documentation but nothing helped. I asked GPT and he told me to do 'gsutil rm gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/PATH_TO_FILE', but the files are encrypted.


but the files are encrypted.

It's a content-addressable storage. Files are not encrypted. Only file names are modified.
File name (path) is essentially calculated as file's md5. This answer By how much can i approx. reduce disk volume by using dvc? has an example.
So, in your case you can run md5 credentials_file and then find and delete the file remotely.

Hello, first of all thank you for your reply. I was able to understand how the encryption of the file name occurs with your tip. I thought they encrypted the whole file, but from what I understand it's just the name.
Despite this, I still find it difficult to remove the file. If I run the command gsutil rm "gs//path_to_bucket/files/md5/hash_md5" I got "dvc.yaml does not exist". Is there any other way to remove it? With dvc perhaps or another tool?
